# Упрощение цикла с проверкой условия. C++

Tags: c++, if, while

Начинаю вспоминать плюсы, есть ли у вас идеи как это упросить функцию читателя в пару строк?
Просьба минусовать аргументированно. UPD выложен полный код с учетом комментариев.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <locale.h>

//буфер в который записывается сообщение
std::vector<char> message;
//индикатор готовности сообщения
short ready = 0;

//функция писателя
void writerAction(void) {
    std::string temp = "textMessage";
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
        message.push_back(temp[i]);
    }
    ready = 1;
}


//функция читателя (если сообщение написано, оно выводится, иначе повтор проверки условия)
void readerAction(void) {
    while (true) {
        if (!ready) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Сообщение: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << message[i];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    //поток писателя (writer.get_id() покажет ид)
    std::thread writer(writerAction);

    //поток читателя
    std::thread reader(readerAction);

    //завершение работы потоков (обязательно)
    writer.join();
    reader.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может быть через тернарный оператор?

Comment: Тут в начале идет busy loop. Так лучше не делать.

Comment: Атомарные переменные и примитивы синхронизации придумали не просто так. Поведение вашей программы не определено. Добавление квалификатора `volatile` к типу переменной `ready` неопределённого поведения **не** отменяет.

Comment: @wololo В теории. На практике для данного конкретного кода сработает...

Comment: Более того, защиты переменной `ready` не достаточно. Общая переменная `message` никак не защищена и не согласована с `ready`. Нет гарантий, что компилятор не переупорядочит операции внутри функции `writerAction`, если такое переупорядочивание не изменит наблюдаемого поведения при однопоточном выполнении. Например, компилятор мог бы переписать `ready` и только потом начать заполнять `message`. Аналогично могут быть переупорядочены операции внутри `readerAction`. Например, содержимое `message` могло бы быть скопировано в впомогательный буфер, и только потом запущен цикл проверки `ready`.

Comment: @Harry, или не сработает. Как это обычно и бывает с неопределённым поведением. [Контрпример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c2103b36fb23fd4).

Comment: @wololo `xx = x; //xx == 100, верно???` С чего вдруг? `x` не объявлена как `volatile`.

Comment: @Harry, Вы тоже `message` не объявили `volatile`. Почему?  Даже если бы и объявили — всё равно UB.

Comment: @wololo Вот с `message` таки согласен, это я зря...

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то

```
void readerAction(void) 
{
    while (!ready);
    std::cout << "Сообщение: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++) std::cout << message[i];
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Но у вас `ready` точно объявлена как `volatile`?

В любом случае такой "процессоропожирающий" подход представляется не лучшим решением...

Comment: short ready = 0;

Comment: Соптимизирует в бесконечный цикл...

Comment: Подход лишь для параллельного выполнения программы

Comment: Бесконечного цикла никак нет

Comment: Да для какого угодно. Вы не говорите, что переменная может меняться в другом потоке...

Comment: Прошу прощения, сейчас полный код прикреплю

Comment: Еще раз и медленно. Объявите `ready` как `volatile`. Но еще лучше к такому способу не прибегать, а использовать те же уведомления/семафоры/иные примитивы синхронизации.

Comment: Вот, сравните вывод: https://ideone.com/MHBMXQ и https://ideone.com/a8OEkR. Всего лишь запускаем сначала читателя — и все, результата нет.. А вот теперь добавим `volatile`: https://ideone.com/Pq9ZDt Все понятно?

Comment: Да, очень наглядно. Спасибо!